# how to show src link in iframe in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a iframe in php page.

```
<iframe align="middle" allow-top-navigation='yes' seamless='seamless' src="http://www.hikvisionindia.com/products/network-camera" scrolling="yes" align="middle" style="height: 1000px;  border: 0px none; width: 900px; margin-top: -140px; margin-left: 50px;"  name="myFrame">
</iframe>
```

I want to show src link in iframe. But its giving blank page. But when I change the src to `src="http://www.hikvisionindia.com/products/network-camera"`  then its showing page.

What is wrong? Please help.

Comment: Have you closed the iframe with `</iframe>` ?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes I closed it. But I am trying it in localhost

Comment: I'm not 100%, but localhost could be the issue as it will conflict with CORS policy

Comment: Right now, I tried it in cpanel. But it giving same blank

Comment: What browser are you using?